# No backup when answering

Tags: feature-request, answers

I was writing an answer on my iPad when it occurred to me A Link May Be Helpful. So I opened a new tab, browsed around for a bit, found something good and switched back to the opened Question tab. ..? No answer? Well, Safari on the iPad must have a really short memory then.

Answered a-new, pasted in my link, then (the folly!) decided I should look up some more facts. After doing so and copying a relevant snippet of information, switching back I found my (much longer!) answer *again* had disappeared! Much gnashing of teeth ensued. Even *then* I fell for it a *third* time, almost reducing me to the proverbial weeping as well.

I finally reclined to the ol' desk and keyboard and typed up my answer in there, a bit more subdued and brusque than in my usual *mien*.

Isn't there an auto-save active during Asking A Question? While typing this, I switched repeatedly to The Other Tab (fully aware of the possible consequences, i.e., having to start this *lovely* and wholly intended long-winding story again from scratch). It seems to work for questions - nothing lost so far.

Am I correct in my understanding that this backup copy is *not* active when typing an answer?

---

(After some more experimenting) Well at least it isn't SO.¹ While answering, I get the little message "Draft saved" popup under the text entry box after 30 seconds of inactivity. Comforting, but alas: after switching away from that tab, the answer is gone! gone, baby!

---

(Apologies for the Thickening of Plot) Just by way of experiment, I clicked the Self-Answer button again. My post is still there! (Give or take an adverb or subordinate clause, I didn't check in detail.) Surely I'd have noticed that it Would Have Been There when attempting to re-enter my original answer. It wasn't.

---

¹ I fully realize that this admission makes my question off-topic for Meta, as well as for SO itself. Perhaps I should ask on Super User or Ask Different instead. Apologies for crying out "foul!"

Comment: That is strange.  I recently typed up an answer on my laptop after commenting to ask for clarification from the OP, but I didn't want to post the answer before the OP confirmed my suspicions of the root cause of the issue.  Later, using Safari on my iPhone, saw that the OP had confirmed my suspicions.  My answer draft was still there, so I went ahead and clicked submit, and the OP later accepted.  Maybe it would have been different if I had started the answer on the iPhone.

Comment: I tend to find Safari on iOS refreshes pages when I come back to the tabs - wonder if that's anything to do with it?

Comment: @JamesThorpe: it may have to do with it — but, on itself, it doesn't explain why my drafts get discarded :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answer drafts *are* saved. If I can take my time with this answer I should be able to take a screen shot and show you.

Ah - here we go:

[image]

The "discard" link shows that a draft has been saved.

Comment: Considering he mentioned _"Safari on the iPad must have a really short memory"_ I'd say he wasn't using the app...

Comment: @Kendra  - I did see that when I first read the post - honest!

Comment: @Kendra: correct. And Chris, not only I don't get to see that button on *answering* but also, now that you mention it, I did not see it when *asking* the above question! I'm 100% positive on that because something rambled in the back of my mind of some pop-up or notification (well, I was close). Never saw this appear (with Safari, iPad 2) (also I got lucky to finish my post). Is that a Known Issue?

Comment: .. How long (time and/or keystrokes) does it take before the Discard text ought to appear? I'll try with typing an Answer - but I don't want to wait for it forever.

Comment: @Jongware it doesn't take that long. A couple of minutes at most, probably less.

Comment: @Jongware When I just tested it by typing "testing" and letting it sit, it only took about a minute. It might potentially be a bug with answer drafts, or an odd hiccup on your iPad. I did a couple quick searches on MSE but didn't find anything about this. I don't have an iPad, or Safari on my Android, to see if it's an issue with one of those, but I can see if I can reproduce on Chrome.

Comment: @Jongware I couldn't get my answer to randomly disappear while switching between tabs, nor could I get it to not save a draft (though it never said "draft saved" or showed a discard link.) So either it's with iPad/Safari, or some odd hiccup.

Comment: It's (my) Safari+iPad. 10 minutes ago I typed a Self-Answer (a long one- again, on purpose). Each 30 Mississippis of inactivity it said "draft saved" (I *knew* I'd seen that somewhere!). Then I deliberately went on a tv-trope clickthrough frenzy in another tab. Coming back, my Answer! It's Gone! Again! "NOOOOOOO!!!!" (which also was one of the 'trope pages I read.)

Answer (score 5):

As an add-on to SO having already implemented this (as of [ChrisF♦'s answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295885/1587329)):

If your iPad forgets the data, you can always **post a partial answer first**, and then edit to add additional detail. (if that fits the spirit of your answer).

As @Deduplicator said in a comment, you need to:

> ... be aware that it will be evaluated immediately, so it should be
>   "good enough" on posting, or you should at least delete (and later
>   undelete) it fast enough to avoid it

After [the change in SO internals described here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem), you no longer get a benefit from being the first answer, so if your iPad forgets such stuff (mobile optimization (?)), it might be a viable answer.

Comment: ... be aware that it will be evaluated immediately, so it should be "good enough" on posting, or you should at least delete (and later undelete) it fast enough to avoid it.