# Edits should have auto-saved drafts

Tags: discussion, feature-request, edits, editor, draft

It's very handy that [draft question & answers are auto-saved](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295885/8112776) but it's unfortunate that the same is [not true for draft **edits** to questions & answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/361485/8112776).

I'm curious whether this was an intentional decision for some reason.

Sometimes after posting an answer, I'll later come across relevant material that prompts me to go back and edit my answer - often substantially - and while trying to be thorough yet not spend *too much* time on one post, I'll end up fumbling or something similar, and **"Boom!***... my lasts 30 to 60 minutes of documented research, images, alternate solution, etc, are "gone".

At least a few times for me it's been a double backspace (intended for the text box) while my palm grazes the laptop's touchpad, and I've just hit <kbd>Back</kbd> and then <kbd>Back</kbd> again to the *"Are you sure you want to leave this page?"* warning.  (Hitting <kbd>Forward</kbd> or refreshing doesn't retrieve the draft edit.)

Surely I'm not the only one who's had an issue with this?

Answer (score 9):

It's a little bit of a pain, but personally, I think it makes sense this way. Implementing a drafting system for edits would be great, but also a real pain for the devs.

After all, you're not the only one who can edit your post. Say you have that draft, come back, and your post has been edited- Now the system has to figure out what parts of your draft to keep.

Do they simply undo the previous edit from another poster, even if it really does make the post better? What if that edit removed a section of fluff? What if that edit took the post from a "meh" to a "great!" just from fixing up presentation and grammar?

Then look at it from the otherside- Do they just drop your drafted changes for things the other edit changed? What if you were trying to remove a paragraph, and someone else reworded it to be more clear? Or visa versa?

The system would have to figure out when to drop what, or when to merge, or what have you. It's not the easiest thing in the world to implement.

My suggestion? If you're re-working an answer that much, try using an outside text editor to edit it. You can always double check your formatting before you submit the edit. As it stands, I don't feel this (while incredibly handy) upgrade would be worth the dev time it would take to sort it out.

Comment: I hasn't considered *other* users editing them too (although I imagine that's a very small percentage of Answer Edits.)    On the other hand, even a **60 second "buffer"** would prevent lost work due to "accidental navigation"; if I'm *intentionally* saving a draft, I'd do it locally on my machine or with [StackEdit](https://stackedit.io/).

Comment: Even in that 60 second buffer, at least one edit can happen. This is a pretty busy site, after all.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not suggested a queue of edits.  Just for the user to be able to recover their own edit.  It's no different than if the user actually remained editing for 60 seconds longer.  There's already logic in place to handle conflicting edits, and to decide which one take priority.

Comment: It turns out, the rate of "users other than the owner" editing an answer is a little higher than I assumed it. Basically, ⅓ of answers (close to **a million per year**) are edited, and ¾ of those edits are made by the owner (original author). Curiously, the *proportion of edits made by the owner* consistently increases annually. [I found this **chart** interesting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1or7w.png) ([Data Source](//data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/832362/)) Also, every year, the overall rate of *edited questions decreases* while the overall rate of *edited answers has increased*.

Comment: That data might be worth adding to your question, rather than lost down here in the comments. :)

Comment: I can certainly say that I myself have run into [edit collisions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360932/what-can-i-do-to-avoid-edit-collisions-that-leave-a-post-in-a-bad-state) multiple times. Having an "edit draft" would probably increase that rate substantially.

Comment: @Kendra - that;data's irrelevant to the question, just interesting facts about edits.  Doesn't change my request.

Comment: @Sudsy1002 - I've also experienced edit collisions.  That's unrelated to the feature I'd like to see.  Not "long term storage"; that wouldn't be feasible.... a "quick recovery" for situations of "oops, wrong button, I just lost all my work"...